# Select OnChange Event returns previous value

Tags: html, reactjs

I ran into a problem with select on change target value. It returns previously selected option. Maybe any one could tell me where is the mistake?

```
change = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    this.props.handleType(this.state.value);
    console.log(this.state.value);
};

 <Select onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
       <option value="" hidden>Type</option>
       <option value="1">Audi</option>
       <option value="2">BMW</option>
       <option value="3">Citroen</option>
       <option value="4">Ford</option>
     </Select>
```

My goal is to get selected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `this.setState` is an asynchronous operation, `this.setState` returns immediately.

So after `this.setState`, `this.props.handleType` is using the `this.state.value` before it was updated to `event.target.value`.

To use the new state value, you need to handle it in the [optional callback parameter](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of `this.setState`.

```
change = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value}, () => {
      this.props.handleType(this.state.value);
      console.log(this.state.value);
   });
};
```

Or, you can simply use `event.target.value`.

```
change = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.handleType(value);
    console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's a common error so hope others can benefit from your question 